# Add DiscussionsList app to default.aspx in SharePoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm trying to add the SharePoint DiscussionsList app to a site defintion. According to [him](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013provision.html) this is how it is done.

```
       <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Left" Title="loc:Main">
            <ZoneTemplate>
                <WebPartPages:ClientWebPart runat="server" 
                    FeatureId="00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108" 
                    ProductWebId="EFFE939B-9566-4A32-BE39-7564AA48247C" WebPartName="DiscussionsList" Title="My WebPart Title"
                     Description="WebPart Description" WebPart="true" ID="DiscussionsList" >
                </WebPartPages:ClientWebPart>
            </ZoneTemplate>
        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

I got the FeatureId from [here](http://www.spsdemo.com/lists/features/all%20sharepoint%20features.aspx). However when I load the page instead of the app this error is displayed and I don't understand it. What does it mean? What did I forget to add?

> The DiscussionsList ClientWebPart in feature
>   00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108 is missing an
>   SPClientWebPartElement with a DiscussionsList Name attribute.
>   Correlation ID: 0525879c-5ed2-70d3-0000-0b7f32a1bc54

Comment: Are you creating site definition using farm solution or sandbox solution? If so why do you need ClientWebPart? You can use usual web part.

Comment: farm soution, but there is no web part for the discussion list, because it's an app and not a web part. If I try to show the discussion list using <View List="...." /> it doesn't offer the same Features like the app does. If I go to the page using SharePoint designer and check what the app did I can see that it adds a XsltListViewWebPart with changing Parameters and a hidden View inside

Comment: Discussion list is the same list definition from feature as it was in SharePoint 2010 only now it is called app for consistency.

Comment: You want the same XsltListView web part but in your custom site definition, right? What page you used to open with SPD ? Default page of some standard site definition?

Comment: Community Home.aspx i think it's called. I'm not at work atm

Comment: I've checked community site feature receiver using reflector to see how it is done in standard site definition. I'm afraid their is no easy way to do that.